# Error Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, vue.js, vscode

Estoy haciendo un programa en visual studio Code, en Lenguaje VUE.

Lo que sucede es que me empezó a salir error en la líneas por los espacios que dejo, y eso se encuentra bien, entonces no se si hay una manera de deshabilitar o si habilite alguna extensión que deba quitar.

Les agradecería que me ayuden.

[image]

Comment: Habria que ver que plugins tenes instalado... y que error te esta dando...

Comment: Un detalle importante, VUE !== lenguaje de programación. VUE === framework basado en javascript.